# Problem returning 2 elements from within a view function

Tags: python, bottle

As it is now the following code cannot return a tuple, with 2 elements, 1st one being a astring and then a response method.

```
@app.route( '/file', methods=['POST'] )
def file():

    pdata = ''
    pdata = pdata + '''<img src="/static/img/arrow.gif" align="left">'''
    filepath = '/home/nikos/public_html/static/files/'

    return pdata, static_file( filename, root=filepath, download=True )
```

The error being returned is:

```
Critical error while processing request: /file
Error:
TypeError('sequence item 1: expected str instance, HTTPResponse found',)
Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 954, in wsgi
    out = self._cast(self._handle(environ))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 894, in _cast
    out = out[0][0:0].join(out) # b'abc'[0:0] -> b''
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, HTTPResponse found
```

What is the easiest way to have a string printed before i return the file to user?

Comment: You can self-answer your own question, if you think the problem (and answer) are useful for other people in the future. If you don't think it's anything useful (e.g., the solution was a trivial thing that was completely unrelated), you can just delete your own question yourself.

Comment: Please delete your comment, as its not an answer to my question.

Comment: A comment is not an answer; it's a comment.

Comment: Did you, or did you not fix the issue, by the way? I see you've removed the comment where you said you fixed the issue, so I assume it's not fixed.

Comment: The comment that i deix was a synatx error i had. The question still remains. Please delete all of your comments and i'll delete the oens answering to you.

Comment: Please delete ALL your comments and let spaxe for actual answers.

Comment: Answers go in the answer box below the questions. Comments are just for clarification requests and such, but don't hamper readability of the question nor answers. If someone has an answer, they'll put it in the right place below your question.

Comment: I understand but because all we wrote is not relevant to my question/clarification kidnly delete all of your comments/remarks please.

Comment: I'll delete them when time comes, no worry and no hurry. Note that your current first comment is now also superfluous, since that respective comment has gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a documentation bug, or at least somewhat unclear in the documentation: mixed iterables are *not* supported.

In the [Generating content](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#generating-content) section of the documentation, it tells you that you can return, among others, iterables and generators. In that bullet point, it states

> You are allowed to [...] return an iterable, as long as the iterable yields byte strings, unicode strings, HTTPError or HTTPResponse instances.

This *could* be interpreted as returning an iterable that contains a *combination* of byte or unicode strings, or HTTPError or HTTPResponse instances.

Looking at the code, however, reveals this is not the case. In particular, taking the traceback from your listed error (around line 894), shows the following for [the current master on GitHub](https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/blob/master/bottle.py#L1040):

```
# Join lists of byte or unicode strings. Mixed lists are NOT supported
if isinstance(out, (tuple, list))\
and isinstance(out[0], (bytes, unicode)):
    out = out[0][0:0].join(out) # b'abc'[0:0] -> b''
```

This piece of code does *exactly* what it says in the comment (including "Mixed lists are NOT supported"): it performs a `.join()` on a list of strings. Since it only checks the first item to see if it's a string, and the first item in your code is indeed a string, it joins the list, failing miserably when it turns out the second element is not a string.

The second half of that code comment should probably be included in the documentation for clarification.

Comment: I see, so now what i have to do to return first the string and then the HTTP Response?!

Comment: That's mostly another question. What you want, can't simple be done. Or try and wrap your first string in a `HTTPResponse`.

Comment: Or perhaps with the use of html template as a middle man this can be achived?